# Transforming points on a coordinate plane to their perspective equivalent?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, projective-geometry

I am currently working on a computer program that can properly plot a point on a 2d coordinate plane that has had its perspective changed to be tilted backwards.  I don't have any information on how much the plane has been tilted.  I can only get the four points of the resulting 2d trapezoid that makes up the tilted plane. Given a point that exists on the tilted plane, how can I translate it properly to the point that it should appear on the viewport?  And given the four points of the trapezoid, can I calculate any tilt or rotation of the perspective plane in relation to the viewport?

My coordinate geometry terminology is a little fuzzy, so apologies in advance if my explanation is a bit unclear.

Comment: This is pretty close to a duplicate of [2D transformation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63409/2d-transformation/63410#comment-152713). See if my answer there helps.

Comment: Thanks, this looks to be exactly what I'm going for.  Now to just digest the info from the Wikipedia article so I can turn it into code.