# Mapping square to a quadrilateral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, multivariate-polynomial

In 1 dimensional space, to map an interval $[0,1]$ into another interval $[a,b]$ we use the function
$$T: [0,1] \to [a,b] :\quad x \mapsto (1-x)a+xb$$
What is the generalisation of this in 2D space (or higher), in other words, what is the function $T$ such that $T$ maps the square $\{(1,1);(-1,1);(-1,-1);(1,-1)\}$ into a quadrilateral $\{(x_1,y_1);(x_2,y_2);(x_3,y_3);(x_4,y_4)\}$[image]

Comment: +1: Others may (deservedly) downvote your question, because of its defects, with respect to this [MathSE article on protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).  I upvoted the question, despite the question's many defects because I find the posed question very intriguing.

Comment: Some answers and references at [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296794/finding-the-transform-matrix-from-4-projected-points-with-javascript), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441597/how-to-calculate-what-matrix-will-transform-specified-points-to-other-specified).